# hangout chat api with personal gmail account

Tags: google-hangouts

I am trying to create a chat-bot with Cloud Functions and Hangout Chat API as part of POC.

I am using my personal gmail & google cloud account for this.
I don't have any GSuite Account.

I enabled the Hangout Chat API on my google clodu account, but while configuring I can see this error on Configuration Tab:

The API "chat.googleapis.com" doesn't exist or you don't have permission to access it
Tracking Number: 6680123491503244043

Can I use Hangout Chat API without GSuite Account ? If yes then what this error means ?

Answer (score 4):

No you can't. Only gsuite users can. May be in future they will open this feature for all. So if you have a gsuite account then so can follow this blog.
https://rominirani.com/tutorial-write-a-hangouts-chatbot-powered-by-google-cloud-functions-890db447bceb